# Holden vectra 2004 automatic gearshift knob

Tags: vectra

**I cant find the part needed for 2004 automatic holden vectra, would the opel vectra gearshift part fit?**

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You need to be a little more specific about which part you're talking about. Can you give us the part number you've found of the Vectra gear shift? We might be able to help then.

Comment: For a gearshift knob, I would visit a breaker's yard. They might even let you try it out.

Comment: Was the holden vectra a re-badged opel vectra? If so it might fit.